# Is it possible to reverse engineer a private key back into mnemonic?

Tags: cryptography

Is it possible to reverse engineer a private key back into mnemonic seed if it is not hard derived?

Is the private key using `subkey` derived from the mnemonic in a soft way? if so can the mnemonic be known from the private key?

Comment: If the mnemonic is hashed to produce the private key then you can't.

Answer (score 2):

Nope. Private keys derive from the mnemonic. A mnemonic can generate a lot of private keys. You can also check the HD wallet spec.

It's a one-way function like you said. Maybe it's a hash function. You can't recover the mnemonic from the private key.

Comment: Is it so? How does the mnenomic then recreate my private key?

Comment: Use the one-way function. `M -> P: f(x) = y`, `P -> M: f(y) != x`.